# How do I make div disappear on click and show what is under it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with class `hide`. Its essentially a `div` with a **black** background. This `div` is suppose to hide the `food` div. So, when you click on the black background, aka if you `click` on the `hide` div, it is suppose to make all the `hide` div's disappear and show the `food` div. However, my issue is that this is not happening. The `hide` div is not showing up. Below is my current code:

```js
function make_disappear(){
    document.getElementByClassName('hide').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.main {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px
    margin: 5px;
    background: red;
}

.hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Y8B7LsB.jpg);
}

.food {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div onclick="make_disappear()" class="hide"></div>
    <div class="food"><img alt="Food!!" src="https://i.imgur.com/1lbkAaY.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div onclick="make_disappear()" class="hide"></div>
    <div class="food"><img alt="Food!!" src="https://i.imgur.com/1lbkAaY.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what specific error messages are you seeing?

Comment: You will also need to use, getElementsByClassName not getElementByClassName

Comment: Are you using jquery as it suggests in your tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using a delegate pattern when animating/transitioning a bunch of elements of the same type or class. After adding `z-index: 1` to the `.hide` elements to get them "on top" of the images in the stacking order, I add a class of `disappear` to the `body` when clicking any of the `.hide` elements. The `CSS` handles the rest, fading out all the `.hide` elements at once. This approach could be used on a wrapper element as well, if `body` feels too high up in the `DOM`.

```js
const hide = document.querySelectorAll('.hide');

function handleClick() {
  document.body.classList.add('disappear');
}

hide.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px margin: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Y8B7LsB.jpg);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .5s opacity;
}

.disappear .hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.food {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="hide"></div>
  <div class="food"><img alt="Food!!" src="https://i.imgur.com/1lbkAaY.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="hide"></div>
  <div class="food"><img alt="Food!!" src="https://i.imgur.com/1lbkAaY.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2rvte9y3/1/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is just how the `divs` are being rendered, the `hide` divs are being rendered first than the food `divs` over top of them since they're both have style of `position: absolute`. Just rearrange their html like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="food"><img alt="Food!!" src="https://i.imgur.com/1lbkAaY.jpg"></div>
    <div onclick="make_disappear()" class="hide"></div>
</div>
```

Or change the `z-index` of the `hide` divs to be higher than those of the `food` divs:

```
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Y8B7LsB.jpg);
    z-index: 100; /* here */
}
```

Your JS also won't work, because, as @wentjun has pointed out, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a node list. You just need to loop through the list to change each display style like so:

```
function make_disappear(){
    var hideDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('hide')
    for (var i = 0 ; i < hideDivs.length; i++) {
        hideDivs[i].style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way you can hide the div without a loop?

Comment: @Shidersz does this by passing the context to the function. You either have to make them disappear with individual clicks or use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

The `getElementsByClassName()` returns a NodeList collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, and in your case, `.hide`.

Doing this `document.getElementByClassName('hide').style` without specifying the index will not work as it is a list.

You will need to iterate through the NodeList, or specifically select the index in the nodelist to target it

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hide')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

To hide all elements in the NodeList, you may do this:

```
[...document.getElementByClassName('hide')].map(node => node.style.display = 'none')
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can have the same concept of the `food` div being hidden by a black image. Then upon clicking the black image, all the `food` div's disappear without using a loop?

Comment: Hmm.. I have updated it, but I have used the map operator.

Comment: May I know why would you not want to use to use a for loop? I believe it achieves the same thing too.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add a greater `z-index` to `hide` elements. Also, note that [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not just one element as you was expecting. So you will have to loop over the collection to apply tthe style to each element.

```js
function make_disappear()
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');

    for (let e of elems)
    {
        e.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.main {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px
    margin: 5px;
    background: red;
}

.hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 99;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Y8B7LsB.jpg);
}

.food {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div onclick="make_disappear()" class="hide"></div>
    <div class="food"><img alt="Food!!" src="https://i.imgur.com/1lbkAaY.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div onclick="make_disappear()" class="hide"></div>
    <div class="food"><img alt="Food!!" src="https://i.imgur.com/1lbkAaY.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to make it disappear all the black images on 1 click. So if you click one black image, all the black images disappear

Comment: @Maggie I will update for that, basically, you will have to loop over the matched elements...